# php file read and write

Tags: php, html, counter

so im learning php and trying to make a php hit counter for a webpage. Now I've written this code according to my understanding. The problem is, when I run the program in terminal, I get the right answer (output is as i expected). When I do an echo on html page, it doesn't work. Here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    #open the file (assuming this file already exists with only 0 in it)
    $file = 'test.txt';
    $file = fopen($file,"r");
    $temp = fread($file, 1024);
    fclose($file);

    #save the number 0 (initial counter to $temp) and delete it)
    $file = 'test.txt';
    unlink($file);

    #open the file (this line just creates the file to write)
    $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
    fclose($file);

    #increase the counter by a number (10 for testing)
    $temp = (int)$temp + 10;
    $file=fopen("test.txt","w");
    fwrite($file,"$temp \n")
    fclose($file);
    #the file only contains a number ($temp - the final counter)

    echo "<h1>$temp<h1>";  #this outputs the correct counter in terminal but only        outputs 10 on html page. ????? 

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You refreshed it yes?

Comment: Yep, it outputs 10 all the time for some reason. Though terminal output comes out correct everytime.

Comment: Your write functions aren't working then, var_dump the fwrite function to find out if its working or not. Could be a permissions thing when you create the new file, you might have to chmod it to 777

Comment: When you run a PHP script from the command line, it is able to access the file system with your usual permissions. But the web server is a different user (usually something like 'www' or 'apache'). That means it doesn't have permission to alter files or folders that belong to you. Check the value of `$file` after the line `$file = fopen("test.txt","w");` — it's probably false. And check your error log too.

Comment: umm Ive tried doing with 766, which should work. how do i check the value of $file?

Comment: the value of $file is a resource ID #70601

Answer (score 0):

I think it's permission problem.
Try to change chmod/chown for example:

```
sudo chown coders:www-data test.txt
sudo chown 765 test.txt
```